# Does adding a graphic card reduce CPU usage on APU systems

Tags: graphics-card, cpu

Im using an A10 5800k amd apu. Since i could imagine that the processing power is shared between the GPU and the CPU i was wondering if adding a graphic card could lessen the load on the CPU.

When i buy a card do i need a new processor to go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An APU is a physical package that contains both a CPU and a GPU, the CPU does not impersonate or share its time doing GPU tasks.  They are both very distinct processing units.  The use of the GPU should not severely limit CPU power available.

I say *should* because sharing the package they also share their memory bandwidth, the GPU side will allocate a certain amount of your system memory and use it to do the work it needs to do.

A dedicated graphics card will no longer need to appropriate system memory, as it has it's own on-board memory, or use the CPU memory bandwidth either and *should* mean that a dedicated graphics card and CPU combo can perform more efficiently than an APU can.

Fitting a dedicated GPU should simply mean that the on-die GPU in your A10 can be disabled, leaving your system memory fully available for the CPU.

You should not need to buy a new processor.

Comment: thanks for the info. I figure i can just get the graphic card right now and upgrade the the CPU later if it should be necessary

Comment: putting in the graphics card definetly made a difference and perfectly what i expected after your answer